# Create numeric choice list

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file with a list of words in it.  How would I read the file and then create a menu so I could choose an animal from the list?  Simple bash script, nothing fancy.

Example: animal.txt

```
dog
cat
lion
bear
```

Example: Desired menu

```
1 - dog
2 - cat
3 - lion
4 - bear

Select choice: 3

You chose a lion.
```

Comment: What have you tried to do? How far did you get, what problems did you face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't generally do requests for scripts here, but I'll help you with the difficult bit.

Assuming a shell with the `select` functionality (such as `bash`). This should get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Select choice: '
select ch in "dog" "cat" "lion" "bear"; do
    case $REPLY in
        [1-4]) break ;;
            *) echo 'Try again' >&2
    esac
done

printf 'You chose a %s\n' "$ch"
```

`select` in `bash` will display a menu and a prompt.  The prompt is given by the value of the variable `PS3`.

The `select` statement is a loop, and in each iteration, the user will have made a choice.  The choice *number* (or whatever the user types) is in `$REPLY`, and the actual menu item is in the variable given to the `select` statement (here it's `$ch`).

The `case` statement in the loop tests whether a valid response was given.  If so (i.e. `$REPLY` was a single digit between 1 and 4), we `break` out of the loop.  If any other thing was typed by the user, a short error message is printed and the loop runs its next iteration.

If you have more than 9 menu items, you may want to test for valid input in a more sophisticated way, since the `$REPLY` value may have more than one character in it.

After the loop, the choice from the menu is available in `$ch`.

Comment: Thank you for this.  It is very helpful and produces the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mapfile`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005?highlight=%28readarray%29#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream) and [`select`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html).

e.g.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t animals < "animal.txt"

select animal in "${animals[@]}"; do
    echo "$animal"
    break
done
```

run:

```
$ ./animal.sh
1) dog
2) cat
3) lion
4) bear
#? 2
cat
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That is exactly what I was looking for.